# Roslyn how to Find / Modify Reduced Linq method invocations

Tags: c#, linq, roslyn

We are using Roslyn to go through the code base and replace database calls and add a new session parameter to any method that previously made them.  So for example:

```
public bool Save(string someData) { // implementation here }
// Becomes
public bool Save(IDriveSession session, string someData) { }
// And Invocations Go From
Save("MyData");
// to 
Save(session, "MyData");
```

This works, except for Linq invocations, especially those that have been reduced.  So for example:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
{
    return ids.Select(GetPerson);
}

// Should transform to

public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(IDriveSession session, IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
{
    return ids.Select(x => GetPerson(session, x));
}
```

It will see and transform this correctly if it was in a foreach loop.  I'm not sure how to get it to see Linq correctly.

Here is applicable CSharpSyntaxRewriter that I am using.

```
public class DriveSessionMethodReferencesRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel semanticModel;
    public DriveSessionMethodReferencesRewriter(SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {
        this.semanticModel = semanticModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(semanticModel));
    }         
    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node) => VisitDeclaration(node); 
    public override SyntaxNode VisitConstructorDeclaration(ConstructorDeclarationSyntax node) => VisitDeclaration(node);
    private SyntaxNode VisitDeclaration(BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var methodInvocations = RewriterUtility
           .GetMethodInvocationsMissingDriveSessionParameter(semanticModel, node)
           .ToList();

        var objectCreations = RewriterUtility
            .GetObjectCreationsMissingDriveSessionParameter(semanticModel, node)
            .ToList();

        if (!methodInvocations.Any() && !objectCreations.Any()) return node;

        node = node.ReplaceNodes(methodInvocations, (n, ne) => ne.PrependArgument(RewriterUtility.CreateDriveSessionArgument()));
        node = node.ReplaceNodes(objectCreations, (n, ne) => ne.PrependArgument(RewriterUtility.CreateDriveSessionArgument()));

        if (!RewriterUtility.HasDriveSessionParameter(node))
        {
            if (node is ConstructorDeclarationSyntax)
                node = (node as ConstructorDeclarationSyntax).PrependParameter(RewriterUtility.CreateDriveSessionParameter());
            else if (node is MethodDeclarationSyntax)
                node = (node as MethodDeclarationSyntax).PrependParameter(RewriterUtility.CreateDriveSessionParameter());
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

Applicable static methods

```
public static IEnumerable<InvocationExpressionSyntax> GetMethodInvocationsMissingDriveSessionParameter(
        SemanticModel semanticModel, SyntaxNode syntax) => 
            syntax.DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
                .Where(invocationExpressionSyntax => invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList == null || 
                                                    !invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments.Any(a => a.ToString() == DriveSessionParameterName))
                .Where(invocationExpressionSyntax => CallsMethodWithDriveSessionParameter(semanticModel, invocationExpressionSyntax));

    // Child Nodes that have method calls with 0 arguments OR without session argument AND the method called takes a new Session Parm.
    // * This may need to be recursive to find nested calls.
    public static IEnumerable<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax> GetObjectCreationsMissingDriveSessionParameter(
        SemanticModel semanticModel, SyntaxNode syntax) =>
        syntax.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>()
            .Where(invocationExpressionSyntax => invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList == null || !invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments.Any(a => a.ToString() == DriveSessionParameterName))
            .Where(invocationExpressionSyntax => CallsMethodWithDriveSessionParameter(semanticModel, invocationExpressionSyntax));

    //Determine if methods need session parm.
    private static bool CallsMethodWithDriveSessionParameter(SemanticModel semanticModel, ExpressionSyntax syntax)
    {
        SymbolInfo symbolInfo;
        symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(syntax);

        return symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols
            .OfType<IMethodSymbol>()
            .Any(methodSymbol => methodSymbol.Parameters.Any(p => p.Type.Name == DriveSessionTypeName));
    }
```

Comment: Do you remember, for example, that you can assignment the delegate variable a some method and pass it into the `Select` method? `Func<int, bool> var = Filter; new[] { 1 }.Where(var);` So you should walk by CFG and change all this assignment, argument passing  and so on. Fo the first step can suggest you try to retrieve semantic info for all of `InvocationExpressionSyntax` nodes in the scope and check if their receiver is `System.Linq.Enumerable`